# Call a hiding macro with a checkbox

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to make a checkbox, calling a macro that hides and unhides columns on Excel worksheet with specific value in cell, but it is not working

I tried the following VBA script

```
Sub Hide_Forecasts()
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("E12:CF12").Cells
        If c.Value = "Forecast" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
Sub Unhide_Forecasts()
    
Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("E12:CF12").Cells
        If c.Value = "Forecast" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

```
Sub CheckBox_For()
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
    Call Hide_Forecasts
Else
    Call Unhide_Forecasts
End If
End Sub
```

Please help me out

Comment: What does no working mean? Are you getting an error, if so what line and what's the error message?

Comment: `Call` versus `Application.Run()` may be something to look into... you'll need to specify if these are all in the same module, etc., and like Warcupine said, elaborate on your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said what type of checkbox you're using - Form Control or ActiveX Control.

For an ActiveX Control right-click the control and select *View Code*.
Use this code that sits behind the worksheet (CheckBox1 will be named after your checkbox).

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Me.Range("E12:CF12")
        If Cell.Value = "Forecast" Then
            'Checkbox returns TRUE/FALSE - Hidden takes TRUE/FALSE so just connect the two up.
            Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = Me.CheckBox1.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

For a Form Control right-click the control and select *Assign Macro*.
Place this code in a normal module.
`Sheet1` is the codename for the sheet (that's the name not in brackets in the Project Explorer).

```
'Form Control can have three values:
' 1     = Checked
' -4146 = Unchecked
' 2     = Mixed - ignoring that this value may occur.
Public Sub Checkbox_For()

    Dim ChkValue As Boolean
    'Is value different from -4146?  Returns TRUE = Checked or Mixed / FALSE = Unchecked
    ChkValue = Sheet1.Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value <> -4146

    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Sheet1.Range("E12:CF12")
        If Cell.Value = "Forecast" Then
            Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = ChkValue
        End If
    Next Cell
    
End Sub
```